# How do I resolve the warning of serializing a BigInt in SQL queries?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, api

I am continuing to get warnings when making API calls that read:

```
TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt at JSON.stringify(<anonymous>)
```

It's not stopping me from querying my database, but I would rather not have warnings thrown at me with every API call.

I'm using `uuidv4` ([`npm` package here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#uuidv4options-buffer-offset)) which returns a random string of 36 characters (including hyphens). My API call looks like this:

```
router.post('/:plantName/:quantity/:description/:addedBy', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('API request to add a new plant');

    const newPlant = {
        name: req.params.plantName,
        quantity: req.params.quantity,
        description: req.params.description,
        addedBy: req.params.addedBy
    }

    db.addNewPlant(newPlant, (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            res.status(500).send('Server Error');
            return;
        }

        res.send(results);
    })
})
```

and exported from `database.js` as `db`...

```
// Add a new plant
const addNewPlant = async (plant, callback) => {
    const newID = uuidv4();
    const query = `INSERT INTO plants VALUES ("${newID}", "${plant.name}", 
${plant.quantity}, "${plant.description}", "${plant.addedBy}")`;

    try {
        const connection = await pool.getConnection();

        const response = await connection.query(query);

        callback(false, response);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        callback(true);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was not with the SQL query, but rather with what I was returning from my middleware. At the end of that first block of code, `res.send(results)` was not sending information that I needed or wanted. I replaced it with `res.status(200).send('Plant successfully added')` and it works as intended.

Comment: what if the result was meant to be sent